# parfor loop has wrong sliced variables

Tags: matlab, parfor

Can anyone explain to me, why the following gives an error for `u` but nor for `h`

```
max_X = 100;
max_Y = 100;
h = ones(max_Y,max_X);
u = zeros(max_Y,max_X);

parfor l=1:max_X*max_Y
i = mod(l-1,max_X) + 1;
j = floor((l-1)/max_Y) + 1;
  for k=1:9
    m = i + floor((k-1)/3) - 1; 
    n = j + mod(k,-3) + 1;
    h_average(k) = sqrt(h(i,j)*h(m,n));
    u_average(k) = (u(i,j)*sqrt(h(i,j)) + u(m,n)*sqrt(h(m,n)))/(sqrt(h(i,j)) + sqrt(h(m,n)));
  end
end
```

I can now substitute `(i,j)` with `(l)`, but even if I try to calculate the related variable, let's call it `p`, according to `(m,n)`, and write `u(p)` instead of `u(m,n)` it gives me an error message.
It only underlines the `u(m,n)`, resp. `u(p)` but not the `h(m,n)`.
MATLAB says:

> Explanation: 
>   For MATLAB to execute `parfor` loops efficiently, the amount of data sent to the MATLAB workers must be minimal. One of the ways MATLAB achieves this is by restricting the way variables can be indexed in `parfor` iterations. The indicated variable is indexed in a way that is incompatible with `parfor`.
>    Suggested Action 
>   Fix the indexing. For a description of the indexing restrictions, see “Sliced Variables” in the Parallel Computing Toolbox documentation

Any idea, what's wrong here?

Comment: See the part [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/#12) about sliced variables.

Answer (score 2):

The problems with `u` and `h` are that they are both being sent as broadcast variables to the PARFOR loop. This is not an error - it's just a warning indicating that more data than might otherwise be necessary is being sent.

The PARFOR loop cannot run because you're indexing but not slicing `u_average` and `h_average`. It's not clear what outputs you want from this loop since you're overwriting `u_average` and `h_average` each time, therefore the PARFOR loop is pointless.